# Type Error : 'str' object is not callable (Python)

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and I've been trying to practice OOP in python with this example:

```
def get_input():
command = input(':').split()
verb_word = command[0]
if verb_word in verb_dict:
 verb = verb_dict[verb_word]
else:
 print('Unkown verb "{}"'.format(verb_word))
return

if len(command) >= 2:
 noun_word = command[1]
 print(verb(noun_word))
else :
 print(verb('nothing'))

def say(noun):
 return "You said '{}'".format(noun)

class GameObject:
 class_name = ""
 _desc = ""
 health_line = ""
 objects = {}

 def __init__(self,name):
  self.name = name
  GameObject.objects[self.class_name] = self

  def desc(self):
   return self.class_name + "\n" + self._desc +     "\n" + self.health_line

 class Goblin(GameObject):
  def __init__(self,name):
  self.class_name = "goblin"
  self.health = 3
  self._desc = 'A foul creature'
  super().__init__(name)

 @property
 def desc(self):
  if self.health >= 3:
   return self._desc
  elif self.health == 2:
   health_line = 'It is badly bruised'
  elif self.health == 1:
   health_line = 'It is barely standing'
  elif self.health <= 0:
   health_line = 'It is dead'
  return self._desc +'\n'+ self.health_line

 @desc.setter
 def desce(self,value):
  self.__desc = value

goblin = Goblin("Gobbly")

def hit(noun):
 if noun in GameObject.objects:
  thing = GameObject.objects[noun]
  if type(thing) == Goblin:
   thing.health = thing.health - 1
   if thing.health <= 0:
    msg = "You killed it"
   else:
    msg = "You hit the  {}".format(thing.class_name)
 else:
  msg = "There is no {} here".format(noun)
 return msg

def examine(noun):
 if noun in GameObject.objects:
  return GameObject.objects[noun].desc()
 else:
  return "There is no '{}' here".format(noun)

 verb_dict ={"say":say,"examine":examine,"hit":hit}

 while True :
 get_input()
```

It seems that this line:

```
 return GameObject.objects[noun].des()
```

returns the Type Error. I'm not sure why this is, and I've been at this for a while. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For the love of Guido, use 4 spaces!

Comment: Please reformat the code with correct indenting so that other users can properly understand the code (I don't even know how to re-tab this for you)

Comment: @Natecat It's supposed to call the function(verb) with noun_word as  the arguement

Comment: @ K.J. Phan Sorry, was on a phone; it wasn't very easy

Comment: How to debug a Python code: read the error, read the line pointed by the error. 99% of the issues solved. If it is not obvious, read the documentation. 0.9% of the remaining issues solved. If the documentation does not cover this point, look up on google, and find a tuto, a post here and so on. 0.09% of the remaining issues solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the desc function, you will have to do it as such:

```
GameObject.desc(parameter)
```

where the parameter can be object[noun]. This is because the desc method belongs to the GameObject class.